# Chemfig reaction to wide for twocolumn

Tags: two-column, minipage, chemfig

For a paper I have to describe certain reactions. I am using the chemfig package to do this. The paper has to be two columns and this is where it goes wrong. When I compile this reaction:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\columnwidth}
\schemestart[][west]
\chemfig{CO}
\+
\chemfig{M}
\arrow{->}
\chemfig{M-[:90,,,,decorate,decoration=snake]CO}
\arrow{->}
\chemfig{M-[:90,,,,decorate,decoration=snake]C}
\arrow{0}[,0]\+\arrow{0}[,0]
\chemfig{M-[:90,,,,decorate,decoration=snake]O}
\schemestop
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

It is to wide to fit in one column. I have tried putting it in a minipage environment but it seems to ignore the minipage and remain the same size.

Is there a way to make my reaction fit in one column?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have added an MWE. It seems the article class and the 12pt make the problem occur somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can use `\noindent` to remove the paragraph indentation which saves half the over-hang, and for the rest you can shrink the arrows a bit (I hope that doesn't change the meaning, my chemistry is a bit rusty)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]


\noindent
\schemestart[][west]
\chemfig{CO}
\+
\chemfig{M}
\arrow[0,.8]
\chemfig{M-[:90,,,,decorate,decoration=snake]CO}
\arrow[0,.8]
\chemfig{M-[:90,,,,decorate,decoration=snake]C}
\arrow{0}[,0]\+\arrow{0}[,0]
\chemfig{M-[:90,,,,decorate,decoration=snake]O}
\schemestop


\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The arrows can be shrunk for a whole scheme: `\schemestart[,.8]` (the `[west]` doesn't do anything in the example) or the whole document or a group: `\setarrowdefault{,.8}`.

Comment: @cgnieder thanks, it's first time I've used the package:-)

Comment: Your solution works! Many thanks for the help!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there's a first time for everything :)